# Draw checker board

Tags: python, homework, turtle-graphics, checkers-draughts

For an assignment, I had to draw a checkers board, with blue and red checkers, in python. What I have works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant and/or efficient way to accomplish this feat? Any and all suggestions are welcome!

```
import turtle

def draw_box(t,x,y,size,fill_color):
  t.penup() 
  t.goto(x,y) 
  t.pendown() 
  t.fillcolor(fill_color)
  t.begin_fill()  

  for i in range(0,4):
    board.forward(size) 
    board.right(90) 
  t.end_fill() 

def draw_circle(t,x,y,radius,color):
  t.penup()
  t.goto(x,y)
  t.pendown()
  t.fillcolor(color)
  t.begin_fill()
  t.circle(radius)
  t.end_fill()

def draw_chess_board():
  square_color = "black" 
  start_x = 0 
  start_y = 0 
  box_size = 30 
  for i in range(0,8): 
      for j in range(0,8):
          draw_box(board, start_x + j * box_size, start_y + i * box_size, box_size, square_color)
          square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white'
          if square_color == 'black' and i < 3:
              draw_circle(board, board.xcor() + (box_size / 2), board.ycor() - box_size, box_size / 2, "red")
          if square_color == 'black' and i > 4:
              draw_circle(board, board.xcor() + (box_size / 2), board.ycor() - box_size, box_size / 2, "blue")   
      square_color = 'black' if square_color == 'white' else 'white' 

board = turtle.Turtle()

draw_chess_board()

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence, the code is well designed. You’ve split the code into simple, reusable functions and the logic is clear.

But there are still improvements to be made:

- You relly on the global variable `board`, which is a bad habit to get into. Instead, pass it as parameter, even for your `draw_chess_board` function;
- The check for the `square_color == 'black'` feels really odd, prefer to check for `'white'` as it is how it will draw and **then** change the background color;
- Using strings to alternate between two states is unnecessarily verbose, prefer to use booleans that you convert to string at the right moment;
- I don't see any reason to define `start_x` and `start_y` and they doesn't contribute mathematically either, you can drop them;
- You could simplify some of your computation by storing intermediate constants into variables;
- You should avoid magic numbers by naming them.

Proposed improvements:

```
import turtle


def draw_box(canvas, x, y, size, fill_color):
    canvas.penup()
    canvas.goto(x, y)
    canvas.pendown()
    canvas.fillcolor(fill_color)

    canvas.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        canvas.forward(size)
        canvas.right(90)
    canvas.end_fill()


def draw_circle(canvas, x, y, radius, color):
    canvas.penup()
    canvas.goto(x, y)
    canvas.pendown()
    canvas.fillcolor(color)

    canvas.begin_fill()
    canvas.circle(radius)
    canvas.end_fill()


def draw_chess_board(canvas, box_size=30, board_size=8, pawn_lines=3):
    half_box_size = box_size / 2
    white_square = False
    for i in range(board_size):
        y = i * box_size
        for j in range(board_size):
            x = j * box_size
            draw_box(canvas, x, y, box_size, 'white' if white_square else 'black')
            if white_square and i < pawn_lines:
                draw_circle(canvas, x + half_box_size, y - box_size, half_box_size, 'red')
            if white_square and i >= board_size - pawn_lines:
                draw_circle(canvas, x + half_box_size, y - box_size, half_box_size, 'blue')
            white_square = not white_square
        white_square = not white_square


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    draw_chess_board(t)
    t.hideturtle()
    turtle.done()
```